# What are these insects

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I am conducting research and these insects were found on my biological sample (sections of pig's femora placed in an artificial water setting).

My location: Mississauga, ON

What species of insects are these?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide the following to receive an answer: Where are you? Where did you collect these specimens? What is your "biological sample"? What sizes are the specimens?

Comment: Were they alive or dead? Do you have photos showing the entire insect larvae (i.e. including not only its head/thorax, but also abdomen and posterior end)?

Comment: The small one was alive, but the larger one was dead as the samples were placed in a freezer.